# Google sheets, ArrayFormula, Query resulting the same item

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, importrange

when i run this formula, it works fine for one row only.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(LOWER(IFERROR(IF(C1:C="test",QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("sheet_ID","Master!A2:AG558"), "SELECT Col14 WHERE Col12 contains '"&$A$1:$A&"'",0),sheet5!L3:L),)))
```

But if there are more rows, I am getting the same result from the col14 matching the A1 only. 
What I mean is the below query will always display the result matching A1. 
How to modify the above query to get results for A2, A3 and so on?

```
 SELECT Col14 WHERE Col12 contains '"&$A$1:$A&"'",0
```

thanks,

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1):

For the query() part try:

```
QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("sheet_ID","Master!A2:AG558"), SELECT Col14 WHERE Col12 contains '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, $A1:$A)&"'", 0)
```

and see if that helps?